# Authorizing a Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Is it possible to make sure that users are not presented with an Authorize dialog when integrating a Google apps script on a google site? when the site is only exposed internally?

Comment: Is it not possible for a large company to authorize these scripts on behalf of their users?

Comment: What you're looking for is either 2-legged OAuth, or Service Accounts support.  You should file a feature request for this in the Apps Script issue tracker (linked from the tag description).

Comment: Use domain wide delegation and publish the app, "execute as me". All the user data will be fetched using Urlfetch with Domain Wide Delegation and REST APIs. This approach is similar to the apps published through G Suite Marketplace where G Suite Admin Authorizes once on behalf of all domain users. Users will then never see authorize dialog.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, there are two use cases primarily supported by Apps Script native Apps beans:

- Execute as deploying user: end users don't need to authorize since accesses deployer's Apps resources
- Execute as end user: end users need to authorize since accesses end user's Apps resources

The third use case you're describing is supported by the Apps Script's [URLFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp) running against the Google Apps APIs.

In many cases the Apps APIs can perform operations on behalf of the user which the authorized client (in this case Apps Script) has authority to perform, so if the client is authorized with admin credentials, the API can often perform operations on behalf of the end user without the end user having to authorize Apps Script to do so.

Unfortunately for your use case, the Gmail Inbox API doesn't appear to be one of those APIs.  For monitoring other end-user inbox information, the [Gmail Audit API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-audit/) may meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your app to execute as the 'user accessing the app', then it is not possible. However, if you set it to run as yourself, then only you have to re-authorize when you make any changes to code. The end users will not be asked to authorize

Comment: Hey, yes that would work - but is this specific case it's a appsscript that read the users current unread count in their "personal" inbox employing your method would then give everyone the count of the script creator.

Comment: IN that case you are out of luck. It would be a serious security flaw if users data could be accessed without their permission.

Comment: but a huge bother for large organisations trying to make plugins that work for all there employees. we are not talking about a public sites script but a sites script for an INTRANET.