# Need help authorizing Google Sheets scripts for domain users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created three scripts (but I think they are all part of the same App?) deployed as a Sheets add-on for my company (all users at our domain). I am an administrator on our account and approved the app for all domain users.

First, users click a button that prompts them to properly name a copy of the current Google Sheet (a payment request form) and saves it in the correct folder on our drive. Then they open this new file and after filling it in, another button on the sheet opens a script that transfers ownership of the file to employee in charge of approving the request, and makes everyone else viewers only. That employee approves the request, then presses a button that runs a script to allow the accountant to edit the document.

The scripts work, but the second two scripts ask for authorization every time they run (even from me). I saw an earlier similar question on [Authorizing a Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353172/authorizing-a-google-apps-script) but I think the 1st answer only applies when running the script as a Web App. I'm willing to do that, but I also barely understand this process (my first time writing a script). Thanks.

1.

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXX');
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  Browser.msgBox("Please rename document. Wait for prompts.");
  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Rename file like this: YYYY.MM.DD Payee Name");
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(fileName, folder);
}
```

2.

```
function setOwner() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId())
  var owner = file.getOwner().getEmail();
  file.setOwner("joe@ourdomain.com");
}
```

3.

```
function setSharing () {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId())
  var owner = file.getOwner().getEmail();
  var user = file.getEditors();
  if (user = "jill@ourdomain.com"){
  file.addEditor("jill@ourdomain.com")
  } else if (user = "sue@ourdomain.com"){
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  } else {
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
}}
```

Comment: Can you please share your scripts? Here is the documentation regarding a Web Apps: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web